# RSpec: Integration test for homepage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, integration-testing

I am trying to learn to test drive the code using RSpec. For this I am creating an inventory management system.

Let the `product` model has three attributes:

1. sku_code
2. name
3. price

And the `warehouse` model have four attributes:

1. wh_code
2. name
3. pincode
4. max_capacity

The application's root url will show the current list of `products` and their counts in all `warehouses`.

I have read that instead of model specs, I should write integration specs first.

So how should I start with writing specs for the homepage and proceed to the next steps?

Comment: This question is so broad as to be pointless. "So how many integration tests will there  be and what should be they called?". Enough to cover the features of your application. Names that are descriptive and tell other programmers what you are testing. "Also will there be any testing for the root url? If yes, how do I go for this?". Integration tests just send HTTP requests and you write assertions about the response. Yeah you should probably test the root path and its not different from testing any other path.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is probably a feature (integration) test made with capybara framework. In your case it could look like this

```
RSpec.describe 'Homepage', type: :feature do

  before do
    create(:product, name: 'Pants')
    # set how many there is in the warehouse (the model is not clear to me, so I'm not guessing this one)
  end

  scenario 'index page' do
    visit home_page_path
    expect(page).to have_content('Paths, 5 items') # Obviously, this depends on how you plan to present that into
  end
end
```

It's just a general pointer on how to start. You can search for [capybara rails tests](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=rails%20capybara%20test&t=canonical&atb=v1-1&ia=software) and get plenty of videos and blog posts to get you started.

So, please try to write something and come back here if you get stuck anywhere.